# Joomla site with global access

Tags: php, joomla, xampp, hosting, wampserver

I use Joomla CMS in order to implement a website instead of using:

```
  localhost/myjoomlasite
```

How can I make my website to have global access from everyone?

I have installed joomla using wampserver to my pc.

Any help will be valuable for me because I have never worked with this staff.

Thank you in advance everyone.

Comment: Are you asking how do you move your site from local host on your pc to a live server?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you will need a domain name as you will need a simple way for others  to reach your website otherwise they will have to type in your IP address to reach your website.

But more importantly a wamp server is great for development but if you intend to run your website on the wamp server there is a lot of configuration and security issues to consider. Your best bet is get a hosting account which will handle all of these issues as you try to publish your website. The cost is minimal and the support is generally very good. Many will give you a free domain name as part of the package. 
It will be the best investment you can make at this early stage.